# How can I change an image in a Crystal report using C#

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report

How Can I change an Image (its an OLE Object) in a Crystal report using C#?

Comment: Do you mean to use a different image or to modify the existing image?

Answer (score 2):

you can add CRAXDRT.dll and CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll to your references
then you can use this code:

```
                CRAXDRT.Report report2 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
                CRAXDRT.Application app2 = new CRAXDRT.Application();
                report2 = app2.OpenReport("YourReportName.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
                for (int i = 1; i < report2.Sections.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < report2.Sections[i].ReportObjects.Count + 1; j++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            CRAXDRT.OleObject to2 = (CRAXDRT.OleObject)report2.Sections[i].ReportObjects[j];
                            CRAXDRT.OleObject to3 = report2.Sections[i].AddPictureObject("NewOleName.bmp", to2.Left, to2.Top);
                            to3.Height = to2.Height;
                            to3.Width = to2.Width;
                            report2.Sections[i].DeleteObject(to2);
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have your image in a Bitmap object,
save it to MemoryStream in Bitmap format,
Create a DataSource, create DataTable in it with 1 DataColumn with type of byte array

```
MemoryStream ms; //contains saved bitmap~!!!
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("img", typeof(Byte[])));
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["img"] = ms.ToArray();
```

also have the report (or subreport of your report) bound to DataSource with schema as above
insert Image object bound to the "img" column to report

Comment: thanks for this. 

row["img"] = ms.ToArray();

helped fixed my codes. :)